# How to properly setup providers for files that just export other classes in Angular2

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

See the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ifJzVKJTmnTZ4madWDK7

We're using Typescript on an Angular2 project that's currently on Angular2-beta.12. We have a directory structure that looks something like the following

```
├── feature1
|   ├── feature1.component.ts
|   ├── feature1.service.ts
|   ├── feature1.action.ts
|   └── feature1.model.ts
├── feature2.ts
├── feature2
|   └── feature2.service.ts
```

feature2.ts contains:

```
export * from './feature1/feature2.service';
```

feature1/feature1.service looks like:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Feature2Service} from "../feature2

@Injectable()
export class Feature1Service {
    constructor(protected _feature2Service:Feature2Service) {
    }
}
```

feature1/feature1.component looks like:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {Feature1Service} from "./feature1.service";

@Component({
    selector: "my-feature1",
    templateUrl: "./feature1.html",
    providers: [Feature1Service]
})

export class Feature1Component implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

feature2.service.ts looks something like:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class Feature2Service {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

When referencing feature2 from feature1 using just the `feature2.ts` file the resulting transpiled code seems to think `feature2` is what should be provided but if we directly reference the `feature2/feature2.service` file in the import the transpiled code sets it up correctly.

Transpiled code when using `import {Feature2Service} from "feature2.ts";` :

```
setters:[
    function (feature2_1_1) {
        feature2_1 = feature2_1_1;
    }
]
```

transpiled code when using `import {Feature2Service} from "../feature2/feature2.service"` :

```
setters:[
    function (feature_2_service_1_1) {
        feature_2_service_1 = feature_2_service_1_1;
    }
]
```

I've played with lots of different ways of structuring a providers block in the feature1.ts file (based on the node_modules/angular2/ts/http.ts file) without any luck.

In the browser and our Unit tests all of this yields errors that look like:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Feature1Service'(undefined). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Feature1Service' is decorated with Injectable.

This seems pretty basic but what am I missing? I'd like to be able to simplify our imports by having these single export files for features, this is an overly simplified example but we have many features that have lots of components and different models so cleaning up the imports so all our developers don't need to know the intricacies of all the directory structures would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: How does `feautre1/feature1.component.ts` look like?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer added to the question write-up

Comment: This should work. I made a try with this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/4rj2p5HlsI2B4UkmXzZE?p=preview. This makes me think to a circular dependency.

Comment: Updated the plunker to more accurately reflect the project issue. turns out it's specific to the inclusion of angular2/router

Answer (score 2):

The first problem: In your feature1.service.ts you are importing FeatureService from feature2.service, but your feature2.service is exporting Feature2Service, so you should change that.

Instead of:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {FeatureService} from "../feature2/feature2.service";


@Injectable()
export class Feature1Service {
   constructor(protected _feature2Service: Feature2Service) {}
}
```

You should use:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Feature2Service} from "../feature2/feature2.service";


@Injectable()
export class Feature1Service {
   constructor(protected _feature2Service: Feature2Service) {}
}
```

The second problem: A service must be registered as a provider before it can be used, so you have two options - or register it as a provider in your base app.component, this meaning that your service will be shared across all of your components, or you can register it only in the component that needs it. Be aware that all subcomponents will inherit it.
So in your feature1.component you should do the following:

```
...
import {Feature2Service} from "../feature2/feature2.service";

@Component({
   selector: "my-feature1",
   template: `
      <span>THIS IS MY FEATURE 1</span>
   `,
   providers: [Feature1Service, Feature2Service]
})
...
```

See the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xNuZdKgT5XDbWKVhjpUZ

Comment: wow you're right. I saw the FeatureService typo which resulted in an error i hadn't seen before, something like 'no provider for feature2service:' which was way more helpful. I'm wondering if switching from beta 8 to beta 14 improved the error messaging but it was pretty obvious what was wrong after fixing that typo. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm currently using beta 13, but the error messaging and stack trace is still very hard to read.

Comment: So While your comments certainly helped fix the plunker it seems that my actual project is still experiencing these issues. I went back and verified the providers are setup correctly and the services are mostly being provided at the root component level.

However; the simple test case i have is a unit test for one of these feature services that depends on another. If the originating service imports the service directly everything works great, if it imports it using that _grouping_ export file it results in different transpiled code and the error message mentioned in the question above still.

Comment: So I figured out the issue with my project... It has to do with Feature2 depending on angular's router. I've updated the plunker to reflect the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/ifJzVKJTmnTZ4madWDK7?p=preview

Comment: You need to add a <base href="/" /> to your index.html:
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kj3AM4KQNB3FzZHiFVnF?p=preview

Comment: yeah I found that and fixed it too. the plunker is working but my app is still not and i can't seem to identify the difference  :(

Comment: Try restarting the build/gulp/watcher. I had similar problems with gulp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108829/discussion-between-randyaa-and-lehel).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with @Inject ?:

```
import {Injectable,Inject} from "angular2/core";
import {Feature1Service} from "../feature1";

@Injectable()
export class Feature2Service {
    constructor(@Inject(Feature1Service) protected _feature1Service:  Feature1Service) {
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Inject(Feature1Service)` is redundant if the parameter has the same type `protected _feature1Service:  Feature1Service`

Comment: i have tried this but with no difference. Also the docs around DI seem to suggest this is unnecessary. i reworked the example and added a plunker, although the plunker seems not to work regardless of what the import looks like so maybe i have something else going on too.